# Identification of a bug, Anobium punctatum?

Tags: species-identification

At first I feared that our old building was attacked by Anobium punctatum. But now, I'm not so sure. 
Each week we find 2-5 of them around our apartment. What are they? and should we worry?

The bugs were found in our apartment in Denmark.

UPDATE Added Picture of Antenna

[image: From beneath]

[image: From above]

[image: Scale in Centimeters]

[image: Antenna]

Comment: If you can get a photo with a clear view of the antennae, that would help.  At the moment, I'm thinking Dermestidae (Carpet and Larder Beetles, among others), but am not certain.  Mind, if I'm _right,_ you _DO_ have a problem, and _WILL_ want them gone ...

Comment: +1 for a great and detailed photos!